# Running running and interacting with docker from python

Tags: python, docker, dockerpy

I have a simple python code I want to run inside a docker container.

```
print("Starting")
while True:
    stdin = input()
    print('read: ', stdin)
    if stdin == 'end':
        break
print("Closing")
```

The docker container is an instance of an image containing the script.
Dockerfile:

```
FROM continuumio/anaconda3 
ADD script.py /
CMD [ "python", "/script.py" ]
```

When I run

```
docker run -i myimage
```

Everything works as expected. I have access to the stdin and I can communicate with the script.

I would like to replicate this behavior in python via either dockerpy or Popen.

I thought something like this will work, but it doesn't

```
p = Popen(['docker', 'run', '-i', '-d', 'myimage'], stdout=PIPE, stdin=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
p.stdin.write("Hello world!")
p.stdin.write("end")
```

Comment: If you're set on using Docker here, you will find it easier to interact with your process using a network API than stdin; you might try wrapping it in something like a Flask wrapper.  Then you can use a library like Requests to make calls into it, without needing to know that Docker is involved (and needing the privileges that requires).

Comment: I want to use Docker for sandboxing the script. Network API seemed like overkill at first but I might have to resort to that solution.